# Unzip files in FTP server using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to unzip files in the FTP location, but when i unzip i am not able to get all the files in FTP server, but when i try the code to unzip files to local machine it is working. I am sure somewhere while writing the data to FTP i am missing something.Below is my code. Please help me on this.

```
public void unzipFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws SocketException, IOException {
FileInputStream fis = null;
    ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
    ZipEntry zEntry = null;

    InputStream in = null;
    FTPClient ftpClientinput = new FTPClient();
    
    FTPClient ftpClientoutput = new FTPClient();

    String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s;type=i";

    ftpClientinput.connect(server, port);
    ftpClientinput.login(user, pass);
    ftpClientinput.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClientinput.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    String uploadPath = "path";
    
    ftpClientoutput.connect(server, port);
    ftpClientoutput.login(user, pass);
    ftpClientoutput.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClientoutput.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    
    

    try {

        // fis = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);

        String inputFile = "/Srikanth/RecordatiFRA_expenses.zip";
        String outputFile = "/Srikanth/FR/";

        in = ftpClientinput.retrieveFileStream(inputFile);

        zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
        while ((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 8192];
                FileOutputStream fos = null;

                OutputStream out = null;

                // String opFilePath = outputFilePath + zEntry.getName();

                String FTPFilePath = outputFile + zEntry.getName();

                // System.out.println("Extracting file to "+opFilePath);

                System.out.println("Extracting file to " + FTPFilePath);

                // fos = new FileOutputStream(opFilePath);
                out = ftpClientoutput.storeFileStream(FTPFilePath);

                // System.out.println(out);

                int size;
                while ((size = zipIs.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {

                    // fos.write(buffer, 0 , size);

                    out.write(buffer, 0, size);

                }
                // fos.flush();
                // fos.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        zipIs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClientinput.isConnected()) {
                ftpClientinput.logout();
                ftpClientinput.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `ex.getMessage()` to `ex.printStackTrace();`.  If something goes wrong, you want to know about it.

Comment: I tried  ex.printStackTrace() and getting null values some times while iterating, i am not getting the cause, even when i debugged.

Comment: “…i am not able to get all the files…” How can you tell?

Comment: I have 5 files  which are zipped, when i tried to extract with the above code, only 2 files will get extracted to FTP. and those 2 files are randomly get extracted. Other files i get it as null

Comment: You need an `out.close()` at the end of your innermost `try` block.